# NHibernate 3.3: executing an Oracle 11g stored procedure with a BLOB parameter

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures, blob, sql-insert

I'm using NHibernate 3.3 and ODP.NET to persist to an Oracle11g database, this is configuration's section relative to:

```
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
```

I'm mapping a byte[] property to a BLOB field and setting a  block to execute the insert stored procedure like this:

```
  <class name="Digital" table="DIGITALS">
    <id name="Id" column="COD_DIGITAL">
      <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="File" column="FILE" />

    <sql-insert>begin PKG_DIGITALS.insert_sp(?,?); end;</sql-insert>
```

*Digital* entity persists ok with size<=32k files; but I'm getting this error [ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested] with size>32k files.

Is it a driver limitation?
How could I workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (NHibernate 3.3.1.4000, Oracle 11g).
NHibernates OracleDataClientDriver sets dbParam.DbType = DbType.Binary. This causes this 32K limit. When one sets dbParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob, the limit is gone.
To archive this I created my own Oracle driver:

```
public class OracleOdpClientDriver : OracleDataClientDriver
{
  protected override void InitializeParameter(System.Data.IDbDataParameter dbParam, string name, NHibernate.SqlTypes.SqlType sqlType)
  {
    base.InitializeParameter(dbParam, name, sqlType);
    var oraParam = dbParam as OracleParameter;
    if (oraParam != null)
    {
      if (sqlType.DbType == System.Data.DbType.Binary)
        // Use Oracle Blob instead of Binary to prevent a 32K limit.
        oraParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
      else if (sqlType.DbType == System.Data.DbType.String && sqlType.LengthDefined && sqlType.Length >= 32768)
        // StringClob params must not be mapped to Varchar2 because that has a 32K limit.
        oraParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
    }
  }
```

Finally, the driver needs to registered in the config:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">MyDataAccess.OracleOdpClientDriver, MyDataAccess</property>
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252511/connecting-oracle-using-odp-net-with-enterprise-library-daab) and [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=451248).
I wonder if this is solution good enough to be integrated into NHibernate.