# Connecting Oracle using ODP.NET with Enterprise Library DAAB

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net

Our application is using Enterprise Library DAAB to support both oracle and sql databases.

One of the Stored Procedure is for uploading Image to Table.
It's a BLOB field and the parameter is set to DbType.Binary.

This functionality works without any problem for SQL, But when comes to Oracle
I hit the 32K parameter size limit issue.

As suggested in SO, I moved the code to ODP.NET, but I am still facing the same problem.

My App.config file setting:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Oracle">
    <providerMappings>
        <add databaseType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            name="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
    </providerMappings>
</dataConfiguration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Oracle" connectionString="Data Source=MYORACSER;USER ID=UNAME;PASSWORD=MYPWD;"
        providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**In my application code I am using enterprise library to access the DB**

```
 Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(); 
 DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(spName);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DOCIMAGE", DbType.Binary, GetByteArrayFromFile(filePath));
 db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "return_value", DbType.Int32, 128);
 int row = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

**I have the following assemblies referenced in my project:**

[image]

**Now when I run the application, Ent Lib DAAP is supposed to be using Oracle.DataAccess.Client, but It is still wired to oracle db through System.Data.OracleClient. So 32K limit is still there.**

[image]

**Why it is not using Oracle Data Provider as I have clearly mentioned in App.config?**

In one post, It is mentioned to use the following snippet as a workaround,

```
DbProviderFactory providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
Database db = GenericDatabase(connectionString, providerFactory);
```

**This one seems working.**

[image]

But the instantiated Database is of GenericDatabase instead of OracleDatabase, may be that's why even this work around still throwing exception when file size is over 32K.

**How do I use ODP.NET with Enterprise Library for 32K size limit issue?**

**RESOLVED**:

I followed **hridya** walk through. 
As he mentioned there were XML comment errors, which can be turned off [(Look here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520853/warning-as-error-how-to-rid-these).
Also there were couple of namespace conflicts which were resolved by choosing Oracle.DataAccess.Client. After these, It compiled successfully.

Here is my code snippet from the sample application I made it to test the changes.
(The sample solution now references new compiled Data and Common dlls.)

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
            DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCode);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "DOCIMAGE", DbType.Binary, GetByteArrayFromFile(filePath));
            db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "return_value", DbType.Int32, 128);
            int rowID = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

I checked command object, now it is of type Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand whereas previously it was System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.

Remember since I have already modified the DAAB to use ODP.NET, I don't need to set the provider explicitly in the config file using providerMappings tag.

But I still get the same error when the file size exceeds 32K, Stepping into the code line by line revealed that the problem is with the DbType.Binary. It didn't get changed to proper OracleDbType.

To make it work I have added one more code fix in Enterprise Lib's Data Project.

File: **\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs**

Method: **AddParameter**

Original code:

```
public override void AddParameter(DbCommand command, string name, DbType dbType, int size,
        ParameterDirection direction, bool nullable, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn,
        DataRowVersion sourceVersion, object value)
    {
        if (DbType.Guid.Equals(dbType))
        {
            object convertedValue = ConvertGuidToByteArray(value);

            AddParameter((OracleCommand)command, name, OracleDbType.Raw, 16, direction, nullable, precision,
                scale, sourceColumn, sourceVersion, convertedValue);

            RegisterParameterType(command, name, dbType);
        }
        else
        {
            base.AddParameter(command, name, dbType, size, direction, nullable, precision, scale,
                sourceColumn, sourceVersion, value);
        }
    }
```

Added condition for DbType.Binary

Modified Code:

```
public override void AddParameter(DbCommand command, string name, DbType dbType, int size,
        ParameterDirection direction, bool nullable, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn,
        DataRowVersion sourceVersion, object value)
    {
        if (DbType.Guid.Equals(dbType))
        {
            object convertedValue = ConvertGuidToByteArray(value);

            AddParameter((OracleCommand)command, name, OracleDbType.Raw, 16, direction, nullable, precision,
                scale, sourceColumn, sourceVersion, convertedValue);

            RegisterParameterType(command, name, dbType);
        }
        else if(DbType.Binary.Equals(dbType))
        {
            AddParameter((OracleCommand)command, name, OracleDbType.Blob, size, direction, nullable, precision,
                scale, sourceColumn, sourceVersion, value);

        }
        else
        {
            base.AddParameter(command, name, dbType, size, direction, nullable, precision, scale,
                sourceColumn, sourceVersion, value);
        }
    }
```

I don't know If this the right way to do it or some other sleek workaround is already available.
But it worked.

Comment: Have you tried using the OracleDatabase instead of the GenericDatabase? I have been looking and I just can't see any issues since you are adding the bytes as a parameter. Please test using OracleDatabase.

Comment: How do I instantiate OracleDatabase using CreateDatabase at the same time telling it to use ODP.NET provider?
DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() doesn't have any overload method to specify provider explicitly. It takes the provider from the config file. Even after I have set my config file right enough to use ODP.NET provider instead of Microsoft's Oracle provider, somehow CreateDatabase not picking up the provider mentioned in config file. It always uses System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Oracle");` instead?

Comment: No, our DAL is written like that. It is calling DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() and creating particular database according the default connection and provider settings in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following steps will give you the correct result.

To replace System.Data.OracleClient with Oracle.DataAccess.Client; and Oracle.DataAccess.Types

Download and install the latest version of Microsoft Enterprise Library ver 3.1 Can be found here:- http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480453.aspx

Download and install the Oracle ODP.Net from Oracle website Your DLL file should be in :-
    C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

When it prompts you to install the source do so by using the checkbox.

If you didn't then run the msi on the following path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Enterprise Library 3.1 - May 2007\src

The code for the library gets stored on the following path C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks

Take a backup of the original src folder in case you need them later - C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src

Open the solution file EnterpriseLibrary.sln And get to the data project under Data Access Application Block

Add Oracle.DataAccess.dll Reference to the Data Project. Your DLL file should be in :- C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\odp.net\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Search and replace the following [ Instead you could download and use the updated DLL thats attached to this article]

File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs
  File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\DatabaseConfigurationView.cs
  File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDataReaderWrapper.cs

Find :- `using System.Data.OracleClient;`
  Replace with:- `using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;`

File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Configuration\DbProviderMapping.cs Class:- DbProviderMapping

Find :- `System.Data.OracleClient`
  Replace with:- `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`

File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Configuration\Manageability\
        ConnectionStringsManageabilityProvider.cs
  Method:- `AddAdministrativeTemplateDirectives`
  Find :- `System.Data.OracleClient`
  Replace with:- `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`

File :- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs
  Method:- `AddParameter`

Find :- `public void AddParameter(OracleCommand command, string name, OracleType oracleType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, bool nullable, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn, DataRowVersion sourceVersion, object value)`

Replace with:- `public void AddParameter(OracleCommand command, string name, OracleDbType oracleType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, bool nullable, byte precision, byte scale, string sourceColumn, DataRowVersion sourceVersion, object value)`

Reason:- OracleType replaced with OracleDbType as the third parameter as that the type name in the odp.net API

File:- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs
Remove:- `[OraclePermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]` -

Haven't got a clue what that does if someone does please brief on feedback session

File:- C:\EntLib3Src\App Blocks\Src\Data\Oracle\OracleDatabase.cs
Find:- `OracleType.Raw`
Replace with:- `OracleDbType.Raw`

Find:- `param.OracleType`
Replace with:- `param.OracleDbType`

Find:- `OracleType.Cursor`
Replace with:- `OracleDbType.RefCursor`

Find:- `parameter.OracleType`
Replace with:- `parameter.OracleDbType`

Compile now and if you get an error do the following Warning as Error : XML comment on - Remove the highlighted error content / replace it with approp comment Hopefully it should compile fine now.

Now the DLL that was generated by compiling the above project can be used against both SqlServer and Oracle [ODP.Net]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I just want to make sure is that the only viable solution? Because the problem here is we are using our unified DAL dll wrapped around Enterprise Lib. So If we have to change Enterprise Lib code, we may have to modify DAL dll too and replace it in number of other applications to maintain version consistency. It's quite a work!!

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. Thanks for your excellent walk-through. I marked yours as Answer. Will this bounty automatically be rewarded to you or do I have to do anything for this?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late on this, but I can't see a good reason why the responder suggested the use of EL3.1 That is very out of date - 5 is the latest version (and was out for almost 2 years before this post) and the OP was using 4.1 according to the code sample. It is much simpler to use ODP with EL5 (have done so myself, utilising the EntlibContrib project) and although I cannot speak for any potential issues with parameter sizes as we do not use BLOBs, EntlibContrib natively allows the use of the OracleDbType so I think it probably wouldn't be a problem.

Just in case anyone stumbles on this post wondering how to get EL5 and ODP playing nicely with minimum fuss I can supply details - PM me.