# Can any one explain how to connect to Oracle using EnterpriseLibrary 6.0

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using EnterpriseLibrary 4.1 [DAAB] and connect to Oracle database 10g using ODP.net.  Now we are using VS2012 and EnterpriseLibrary 6.0 [DAAB].  I dont find the correct steps to connect to Oralce.

Based on your some friends, and documentation, I was able to create code.  But the problem is the config file.

Please direct me to the correct settings in the config file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a pretty good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13252511

Answer (score 0):

The Most important is in the configuration file, the tag **system.data**.  Because, when the ODP.net was installed, it is not inserting the proper values in the Machine.config.  So, we need to add those entries in the .config file.

### #Code

DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();

database = factory.Create("DBinstanceName");

### #ConfigSection Entries

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="oracleConnectionSettings"    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.Configuration.OracleConnectionSettings,     Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
```

### Connection Entries

```
<oracleConnectionSettings>
    <add name="CNQ" />
</oracleConnectionSettings>
```

### System.data Entries

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

### Connection Entries

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CNQ" connectionString=" Min Pool Size=0;Connection Lifetime=120;Max Pool Size=50; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST= XXXX.com)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = cnq) (SERVER = DEDICATED) ) );"
        providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```